# Calculate number of rows in constant 2D c-array

Tags: c++, c

alculating number of elements in array is easy:

```
int myarr[] ={1,2,3};
int myarrsize = sizeof(myarr)/sizeof(myarr[0]);
```

but, how can I calculate number of rows in 2D array?

```
int my2Darr[][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
int my3DarrRows = ???
```

Is it possible?

Comment: what's the number are you expecting for rows 2 or 3? below answers get 3

Comment: This doesn't compile. `error: declaration of 'my2Darr' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first`

Comment: @billz: Thank you for compile-error remark. I've corrected the code.

Comment: what about columns?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The same way.  So either:

```
sizeof(my2Darr)/sizeof(my2Darr[0])
```

or:

```
sizeof(my2Darr[0])/sizeof(my2Darr[0][0])
```

depending on what you mean by "rows".

Comment: Thanx! The first one is what I've ment. The second is obviously not the question, as the compiler allows only outermost dimension to be not specified (as billz pointed out). So sizeof(my2Darr[0])/sizeof(my2Darr[0][0]) would return the constant, you've specified in the definition of the array :-)

Answer (score 5):

Your code won't compile unless you specify second array size which you know its size already:

```
int my2Darr[][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
             ^^^
```

So the question come to 
***how can I calculate number of rows in 2D array?***

```
template <class T, unsigned N, unsigned N1>
int length(T (&)[N][N1])
{
    return N;
}
```

If you want column size, return `N1` instead

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed the code in the questions. (Was actually wandering about compiler errors in VS, returned to SO and found the reason :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
sizeof(arr[0])/sizeof(arr[0][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

**valid one is**

sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);

**The below one does not work**
sizeof(array[0])/sizeof(array[0][0]);